# How to attach an order PDF in an order confirmation email?

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce, pdf

I am currently adding a link to download the order PDF in the confirmation email with `{{ order.getPdfUrl() }}` but also want this to be an attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (Craft Commerce 1.1) there is no way to attach the PDF in an order status email, it can only be a link to download the PDF. For now, I suggest you make a feature request here: http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/295386-commerce/filters/top

Answer (score 2):

You can send an email via your plugin's `init()` function like so:

```
craft()->on( 'email.onBeforeSendEmail', function( Event $event ){
    $email = $event->params['emailModel'];
    $attachment = array(
        'path'     => '/var/www/public/assets/downloads/filename.pdf',
        'name'     => 'File Title',
        'encoding' => 'base64',
        'type'     => 'application/pdf'
    );
    $email->addAttachment($attachment['path'], $attachment['name'], $attachment['encoding'], $attachment['type']);
});
```

Obviously, you'll want to do some checks on the `Event` and pass that off to a service to determine the logic for what should actually be attached.