# Is it possible to add an attachment to a Craft Commerce order status email?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, emails

I'm trying to figure out a way to attach an asset file to a Craft Commerce order status email when a user purchases a product- the user would be purchasing the file and I'd like to attach it to the order status email that's sent upon completion of purchase.

I see that the Contact Form plugin has a similar functionality:

https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm/blob/master/contactform/services/ContactFormService.php#L54

Is it possible to do something similar in Craft Commerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [How to attach an order PDF in an order confirmation email?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15383/how-to-attach-an-order-pdf-in-an-order-confirmation-email/15417#15417), it is currently not natively possible as of Craft Commerce 1.1.